# Select nothing when omni completion activated?

Tags: autocompletion

When  omni completion activated,a menu pop up waiting to select,which key could i press if i want to select nothing in the menu and input whatever else?

Comment: :help ins-completion, probably, or maybe :help popup-menu or :help pum ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to cancel completion and go back to where you were before you started it.

See [`:help complete_CTRL-E`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#complete_CTRL-E):

> When completion is active you can use `CTRL-E` to stop it and go back to the originally typed text. The `CTRL-E` will not be inserted.